# I am getting following error in Theano 0.8.2

Tags: python, theano

`AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'gof'`

in the following code:

`except (OSError, theano.gof.cmodule.MissingGXX) as e:`

However, there is gof folder inside theano.

Any help please

Comment: Have you tried importing the exception `MissingGXX` (i.e. `from theano.gof.cmodule import MissingGXX`) at the top of your module and just catching this instead of the full `theano.gof.cmodule.MissingGXX`?

Comment: Thanks Mike. I reinstalled the Theano and now getting Kernel can not start error when opening spyder IDE.

Comment: When I uninstall Theano, then spyder is working properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience using spyder IDE.  Also, I have tested both ways of catching that exception and both seem to work fine for me.  What version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.5